не открывается новый терминал linux
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с терминалами линукс. Я установил образец debian 11 на oracle virtual box, начал проходить основы работы в терминале линукс. Все шло гладко до тех пор, пока в лабораторной работе не появилась необходимость работы с несколькими терминалами. В лекции новый терминал открывался сочетанием alt + f1-f6, у меня же никак не реагирует. Пробовал так же ctrl + alt + f1-f6, но безрезультатно. Клавиатура работает, проверял на сайте это же сочетание клавиш и всё работало. Через экранную клавиатуру тоже реагирует, а вот на физической ничего не происходит.
Единственное, пробовал через команду chvt ЦИФРА переключаться, все работало, но хотелось бы как у нормальных людей через комбинацию.
Такое ощущение, что происходит конфликт именно с основной ОС. Пробовал и включать и отключать автозахват клавиатуры, мыши, в общем так и не добрался до решения. Помогите, пожалуйста

Поставьте tmux/screen и работайте в одном терминале с несколькими панелями.

Если в VirtualBox, значит в нём жмите Правый Ctrl + F1-F6

@andreymal правый ctrl по умолчанию был задан хост комбинацией, которая переключала акцент с основной ос на виртуальную и наоборот.
с ним не работает.
поменял хост клавишу на другую, чтобы освободить правый ctrl, но без изменений :(

В том и суть, что нажимать F1-F6 нужно именно через хост-клавишу
